# Serving files on S3 bucket through Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-s3, rename, cloudflare

I wanted to serve S3 bucket files through Cloudflare network, but encountered some issues. Integration instructions are given [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-), but they are suitable only for new buckets since bucket is required to be named `subdomain.domain.com` while my bucket is named `domain`.

Are there any other solutions to use CloudFlare with S3  without copying files from one bucket to another - like setting some redirects etc.? The problem is that my bucket contains more than 6 million files and that take 200 GB of storage.

Amazon S3 pricing rules are also hard to understand. I struggle to find information how much it costs to transfer information from one bucket to another if they are in the same location.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Amazon S3 requires that the cname conforms to the bucket name as you already found out. So basically you'll have to fix the name.

Here https://serverfault.com/questions/349460/how-to-move-files-between-two-s3-buckets-with-minimum-cost you can find how to copy files between buckets with minimum cost. Within the same zone, and with the right tools, you will not incur bandwidth costs, only the duplicate storage costs for the duration and access costs, details in the linked answer.

Your link to the cloudflare docs doesnt seem to be working anymore, this is the correct link: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-